# Image and text styling issue with Google maps infoWindow: different outcomes for images and text with the same css

Tags: html, css, google-maps, styling

I want to avoid giant infoWindows so this is the string for their html content:

`var contentString = "<h3>"+this.type+"</h3>"+
                "<h4 class = 'view-text'>" + this.title + "</h4>"+
                "<p class = 'view-text'>"+this.desc+"</p>"+
                "<img class = 'view-img' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location="
                +this.cords.lat+","+this.cords.lng+"'></img>";`

This is the css:

`.view-img,
.view-text {
    max-width: 15vw;
}`

At the end, the image and text widths are different:
http://imgur.com/a/ArFJF

How can I make it so that the text and image are aligned?

Comment: try adding `height="50" width="50"` to the `<img>`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling div elements, using infoWindow maxWidth property solved the issue with giant infoWindows I was initially trying to solve.

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: infoWindowContent(place),
        maxWidth: 200
    });
```